# Can I set a Excel Application Object to point to an already open instance of Excel?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am currently trying to create an export tool to push data into Excel.  However after the first push, Excel is left open, and sometimes a user may want to leave Excel open while they push more data to another page in the same excel sheet.    I usually just release the COM objects once the export is done.  The way my methods work right now involves opening a new instance of excel every time I export...

would it be beneficial to create a global instance of the application to use continuiously from the point I begin exporting until the point of the Excel application being closed?

Should I be using event handlers to detect when Excel has been closed so I know when to release the COM objects?

If I do try to make a global instance of an Excel Application, I can instantiate it and wait to release it, that way I don't need to try and find open instances of excel again..  but if I needed to find, and assign to a variable, an open instance of Excel (that has previously existed in code but had the COM objects released), how would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used this in the past.  tPath is the path to my excel file that should be opened/reused.

```
Dim exApp As New Excel.Application

'finds the workbook.  If it is already open, then it uses that.  Otherwise, it opens in new instance
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
wb = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(tPath)
exApp = wb.Parent
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for.  Or it will best help when I am opening excel files, as I don't want the same one opening a second time..

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Interop Library to point to the open excel-app

(This code is written in C# so there could be some minor change for VB.Net)

```
oExcel = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
```

Comment: The (Excel.Application) part is for casting?  Otherwise this works just fine,  I put and import statement in for it.  I tried running a .Quit() function on the object right after and I got an error..  I'll play around a bit more before explaining the details..

Comment: Yes, it's for casting (Sorry for the late answer), but it seems that your problem is already solved. ;-)