# get a handle of the already open instance of Excel and run a macro inside, from Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

This is not a duplicate of:
[Can I set a Excel Application Object to point to an already open instance of Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282310/can-i-set-a-excel-application-object-to-point-to-an-already-open-instance-of-exc)

The idea is to execute a VBA sub contained in an Excel instance that is already open **from Outlook**

I am running the VBA sub as part of a rule in Outlook.

This is my code:

```
On Error Resume Next
        Dim tPath As String
        tPath = "X:\Lucas\LucasSheet.xlsm"
        Dim exApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        wb = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(tPath)
```

Unfortunately at this point, when running in debug mode I can see that wb is equal to `Nothing`

```
        Set exApp = wb.Parent
        usedSub = "PrintSingle"
        exApp.Run usedSub            
        wb.Close False
```

Is it possible to make this code work in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new Excel Application in the code:

```
 Dim exApp As New Excel.Application
```

You need to get the running Excel instance :

```
exApp =  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

See [Access running instances of Excel in VB](https://xldennis.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/access-running-instances-of-excel-in-vb/) for more information and sample code in VB.NET.

Use the `Run` method of the Application class to run the VBA macro programmatically.

Comment: what if I have 5 instances of excel running?

Comment: I think the issue is that I can't get System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal to work.

Comment: Why do you need to have 5 Excel instance running?

Comment: I often have more, at the point of writing this reply I have seven, it's a necessity in my role.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35343847/9700298) is code which gets _all_ instances.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a function that will attach to a running instance of Excel and then look for a workbook by name.

```
'@Description "Return the open Excel workbook"
Public Function GetHandleForExistingWorkbook(ByVal fullPath As String) As Object
    On Error GoTo openExcel
    
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    
    Dim wb As Object
    For Each wb In excelApp.Workbooks
        If wb.FullName Like fullPath & "*" Then
            Set GetHandleForExistingWorkbook = wb
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb

    Exit Function
    
openExcel:
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        ' Open it if it wasn't already open
        Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        GetHandleForExistingWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fullPath)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Unhandled exception: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    End If

End Function
```

Once you know you are in the correct place you can run the macro by calling on the Excel Application object:

```
Public Sub RunMacroInOpenWorkbook(ByVal fullPath As String, ByVal macroName As String, _
Optional ByVal macroParameters As String = "")

    Dim theWorkBook As Object
    Set theWorkBook = GetHandleForExistingWorkbook(fullPath)
    theWorkBook.Application.Run "'" & theWorkBook.Name & "'!" & macroName, macroParameters
    theWorkBook.Close False
End Sub
```

Then your code to use this would look like this:

```
    Dim tPath As String
    tPath = "X:\Lucas\LucasSheet.xlsm"
    usedSub = "PrintSingle"
    RunMacroInOpenWorkbook tPath, usedSub
```

Comment: Note that `GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` will return some instance of Excel and this might not be what you want if there are multiple instances running. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35343847/9700298) is code which gets _all_ instances.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the workbook name when using the `Application.Run` command.

Try using this:

```
    exApp.Run wb.Name & "!" & usedSub ' must include workbook name
```

Comment: you are opening a sheet instead of referring to one that is already open, that's not the point of my question.

Comment: this is irrelevant to the question as `wb` is equal to`Nothing`. Your `wb.Name` will fail in my question.

Comment: Have you tried using an `Auto_Open` macro in the workbook?  Also, your question needs the [.Net] tag and more explaining. "How can i loop through the multiple open Excel sessions, looking for a workbook and setting a reference to that workbook?"

Comment: I want to run a macro on a sheet that's constantly open from Outlook, what's the reasoning behind adding anything to auto open?